# How to extract information about a PV attached to a pod from an app running in another pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

Among a big stack of orchestrated k8s pods, I have following two pods of interest:

1. Elasticsearch pod attached to a PV
2. A tomcat based application pod that serves as administrator for all other pods

I want to be able to query and display very minimal/basic disk availability and usage statistics of the PV (attached to pod #1) on the app running in pod #2

Can this be achieved without having to run a web-server inside my ES pod? Since ES might be very loaded, I prefer not to add a web-server to it.

The PV attached to ES pod also holds the logs. So I want to avoid any log-extraction-based solution to achieve getting this information over to pod #2.

Answer (score 2):

You need get the PV details from kubernetes cluster API, where ever you are.

#### Accessing the Kubernetes cluster API from within a Pod

When accessing the API from within a Pod, locating and authenticating to the API server are slightly different to the external client case described above.

The easiest way to use the Kubernetes API from a Pod is to use one of the [official client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/). These libraries can automatically discover the API server and authenticate.

#### Using Official Client Libraries

From within a Pod, the recommended ways to connect to the Kubernetes API are:

- For a Go client, use the official [Go client library](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/). The rest.InClusterConfig() function handles API host discovery and authentication automatically. See [an example here](https://git.k8s.io/client-go/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration/main.go).
- For a Python client, use the official [Python client library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/). The config.load_incluster_config() function handles API host discovery and authentication automatically. See [an example here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/in_cluster_config.py).
- There are a number of other libraries available, please refer to the [Client Libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) page.

In each case, the service account credentials of the Pod are used to communicate securely with the API server.

#### Reference

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#accessing-the-api-from-within-a-pod

Comment: For elastic search the information i was looking for was provided by their APIs /nodes/stats .